# Display subheading with excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display subheading and excerpt of my blog post

```
<?php { the_subheading(); the_excerpt();  } ?>
```

when i used the above code it displays my subheading, follwed by `<p>` and followed by my `excerpt()`. I want to remove `<p>`. Is it possible? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> instead of <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

solved my problem. Hope it will be useful to someone!